# Weird behaviour with pandas cut, groupby and multiindex in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this one,

```
                        Continent % Renewable
Country                                      
China                        Asia           2
United States       North America           1
Japan                        Asia           1
United Kingdom             Europe           1
Russian Federation         Europe           2
Canada              North America           5
Germany                    Europe           2
India                        Asia           1
France                     Europe           2
South Korea                  Asia           1
Italy                      Europe           3
Spain                      Europe           3
Iran                         Asia           1
Australia               Australia           1
Brazil              South America           5
```

where the `% Renewable`is a column created using the cut function,

```
Top15['% Renewable'] = pd.cut(Top15['% Renewable'], 5, labels=range(1,6))
```

when I group by `Continent`and `% Renewable` to count the number of countries in each subset I do,

```
count_groups = Top15.groupby(['Continent', '% Renewable']).size()
```

which is,

```
Continent      % Renewable
Asia           1              4
               2              1
Australia      1              1
Europe         1              1
               2              3
               3              2
North America  1              1
               5              1
South America  5              1
```

The weird thing is the indexing now, if I index for a value that the category value is > 0 this gives me the value,

```
count_groups.loc['Asia', 1]
>> 4
```

if not,

```
count_groups.loc['Asia', 3]
>> IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

shouldn't it give me a 0 as there are no entries in that category? I would assume so as that dataframe was created using the groupby.

If not, can anyone suggest a procedure so I can preserve the 0 nr of countries for a category of `% Renewable`?

Comment: Try `count_groups.get(('Asia', 3), 0)`

Comment: I guess that would be the answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Series with MultiIndex. Normally, we use tuples for indexing with MultiIndexes but pandas can be flexible about that.

In my opinion, `count_groups.loc[('Asia', 3)]` should raise a KeyError since this pair does not appear in the index but that's for pandas developers to decide I guess.

To return a default value from a Series, we can use `get` like we do in dictionaries:

```
count_groups.get(('Asia', 3), 0)
```

This will return 0 if the key does not exist.